# reading an xml file into R created from a deprecated ImageJ Error: XML content does not seem to be XML

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, imagej

I'm using XML package in Rstudio to try to import the following xml file into R. When I use any of the XML functions I get the following result:

```
data <- xmlParse(file = "Cell_Counter_SJJ_094_01_2_Counting.xml")
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 
'Cell_Counter_SJJ_094_01_2_Counting.xml'
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CellCounter_Marker_File>
 <Image_Properties>
     <Image_Filename>SJJ_094_01_2_Counting.tif</Image_Filename>
 </Image_Properties>
 <Marker_Data>
     <Current_Type>2</Current_Type>
     <Marker_Type>
         <Type>1</Type>
         <Marker>
             <MarkerX>7172</MarkerX>
             <MarkerY>4332</MarkerY>
             <MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
         </Marker>
         <Marker>
             <MarkerX>7172</MarkerX>
             <MarkerY>4140</MarkerY>
             <MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
         </Marker>
         <Marker>
             <MarkerX>7186</MarkerX>
             <MarkerY>4072</MarkerY>
             <MarkerZ>1</MarkerZ>
         </Marker>
     </Marker_Type>
 </Marker_Data>
</CellCounter_Marker_File>
```

Any ideas why it doesn't read it as an XML file?

Comment: I copied the XML from your question to a file and I don't see that error. [It may be a misleading error message](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Misleading-error-message-XML-content-does-not-seem-to-be-XML-td4728488.html) due to the XML file not being in your current working directory.

Comment: Could this be a result of accessing the XML file from a network drive on a windows system? I will test out in a moment and see if that is the issue.